# glassfish web service tester not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, soap, glassfish

I am learning about SOAP web services and have written a simple dynamic web app with a plain old java class annotated with @WebService (i am using eclipse-jee-neon-1-RC3)
I have not created any client for it and just Testing it from admin console.
(WebService Endpoint)

The wsdl link is working fine but Tester link shows

HTTP Status 500: Internal Server Error

Exception : java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: bundle://164.0:1/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'bundle' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.

Please help with this

Comment: Kepler is a very old version (more than 3 years old!), you should move to Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Tried with Eclipse Neon also, still not working